# Kansas Insect (Black Bee/Wasp?) Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, bees

I live in Kansas (Pottawatomie County), and I found a bee-like insect in my bedroom. The creature looked like this:

[image]
[image]

The insect about 5 cm long in size (as you can compare it with the window blind), and it appeared once in the morning (9 AM) and once in the evening (8 PM). It seems to be dark in body color, with some yellowish color on its legs and wings.

Could you please tell me what is the name of this bee-like species? And is this thing toxic / dangerous to human?

In addition, what would be the best way to kill it? Do spiders prey on it? Does ultraviolet (UV-A) light attract this insect so that I can kill it with a bug zapper? Or should I call the pest control for help? Edit: Or do I have to kill it at all?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thank you so much for the help! So would it be safe to say that these wasps' sting is unlikely to cause life-threatening symptoms?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Hello, thanks for helping the OP. Do you think you could make your comment an answer? As you know, it's not ideal to have answers in comments.

Comment: @BryanKrause - Sure, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a paper wasp; it looks like *maybe* a Northern Paper Wasp (better photo needed.)

> [Northern Paper Wasps](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.php?identification=Northern-Paper-Wasp) are most commonly found in the Midwest states. They are likely to build nests near humans as that is where a lot of wood can be found (homes, barns, sheds, fences, firewood, landscaping, etc.). The wasps use wood to create their nest.

They are 15mm to 21mm (0.59" to 0.82") long, which fits your photograph. They are considered beneficial to keeping caterpillars under check:

> Northern Paper Wasps are so effective at this pest control that they are almost welcome in organic gardens since their presence negates the need for chemical pesticides.

> ...is this thing toxic / dangerous to human?

It stings, the sting can be painful and may cause localized swelling, but they aren't likely to sting unless you irritate it (e.g. try to kill it and miss, etc.) If you're allergic to hymenoptera stings, leave it alone and get someone else take care of it! If there are children in the house, it is probably better to kill it than to risk their getting stung.

If it appears daily, there is probably a nest somewhere in your house (a wall or attic) with a small space where the wasp can access your interior. The larger the nest, the more easily wasps get irritated, so if you ever see two wasps in your house at the same time, call an exterminator with experience in wasp nest destruction. If it were a bee, you would call a nest extractor, who could relocate the hive.